# Stochastic integral: $E\left(\int^1_0(W(s))\,ds\int^1_0t(W(t)\right)\,dt$

Tags: measure-theory, integration

I need to calculate the expectation of the product between the integral of a Wiener process and the expectation of a Wiener process. Is the same as the expectation of the product between the integral and comprehensive Wiener by Wiener $t$. The integrals are evaluated between $0$ and $1$.

Necesito calcular la expectativa del producto entre la integral de un proceso de Wiener y la expectativa de un proceso de Wiener. Lo que es lo mismo la expectativa del producto entre la integral de Wiener y la integral de $t$ por Wiener. las integrales se evaluan entre $0$ y $1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For every $s$ and $t$, $\mathbb E(W(s)W(t))=\min(s,t)$.
Apply this to
$$
\mathbb E\left(\int_0^1W(s)\mathrm ds\cdot\int_0^1t\,W(t)\mathrm dt\right)=\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^1t\cdot\mathbb E\left(W(s)W(t)\right)\mathrm dt\mathrm ds.$$